# I am trying to make a 4 way, 8 way connected image adjacency matrix from a 2d array of image pixels in python, Is there any efficient way to do this

Tags: python, image-processing

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np 
import scipy.sparse as s
print('reading a coloured image')
im = Image.open('image.tiff')
#im.show()
colour_pix= list(im.getdata()) # get 3 tuple of pixel intensity
 

print('converting image to grayscale')
gray= Image.open('image.tiff').convert('L')
#gray.show()
gray_pix=list(gray.getdata()) #f=get grayscale intensity
 
#arr= np.asarray(gray)
#plt.imshow(arr,cmap='gray',vmin=0,vmax=255)
#plt.show()
#pix_val=list(gray.getdata())

#pix_val_flat=[x for sets in pix_val for x in sets]
#im.show()
#print('printing pix_val')
#print(pix_val)
#print('printing pix_val_flat')
#print(pix_val_flat)
#im2= Image.new(im.mode,im.size)
#im2.putdata(pix_val)
#im2.show()
print('Graph part')
print('last me ')

#Graph definition for undirected graph using adjacency matrix 
def nest_list(list1, rows, columns):
    result=[]
    start=0
    end=columns
    for i in range(rows):
        result.append(list1[start:end])
        start+=columns
        end+=columns
    return result
array = (nest_list(gray_pix,gray.size[0],gray.size[1]))

def adjacency(image, connect, patch_size=(1, 1)):
    r, c = image.shape[:2]
    r = r / patch_size[0]
    c = c / patch_size[1]
    
    if connect == '4':
        # constructed from 2 diagonals above the main diagonal
        d1 = np.tile(np.append(np.ones(c-1), [0]), r)[:-1]
        d2 = np.ones(c*(r-1))
        upper_diags = s.diags([d1, d2], [1, c])
        return upper_diags + upper_diags.T
    
    elif connect == '8':
        # constructed from 4 diagonals above the main diagonal
        d1 = np.tile(np.append(np.ones(c-1), [0]), r)[:-1]
        d2 = np.append([0], d1[:c*(r-1)])
        d3 = np.ones(c*(r-1))
        d4 = d2[1:-1]
        upper_diags = s.diags([d1, d2, d3, d4], [1, c-1, c, c+1])
        return upper_diags + upper_diags.T
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid parameter \'connect\'={connect}, must be "4" or "8".'
                     .format(connect=repr(connect)))

a = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
adj = adjacency(a, '4').toarray()
print (a)
```

I am trying to implement an image segmentation algorithm based on a minimum spanning tree
My overall goal is to read an image and reading the image into a matrix containing pixel values, then now I want to make an 8 way or 4 way connected graph form this matrix,making a graph i need adjacency matrix, since my image is 512x512 ,adjacency matrix will of order (512*512)x(512*512). After creating adjacency matrix I will apply kruskal's algorithm on adjacency matrix and then cut the k most weighted edges from MST to get k+1 components in a graph, then I will retreive the original image from this MST with k cuts.Please help me provide the strucuture for  4 way and 8 way connected adjaceny matarix and how can I map back the adjacency matrix into image.

I am also getting the following error while running it in spyder

```
 runfile('C:/Users/Anurag Uikey/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Anurag Uikey/.spyder-py3')
reading a coloured image
converting image to grayscale
Graph part
last me 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-bbd2bd36a228>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Anurag Uikey/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Anurag Uikey/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\Anurag Uikey\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Anurag Uikey\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Anurag Uikey/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 71, in <module>
    adj = adjacency(a, '4').toarray()

  File "C:/Users/Anurag Uikey/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 53, in adjacency
    d1 = np.tile(np.append(np.ones(c-1), [0]), r)[:-1]

  File "C:\Users\Anurag Uikey\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 223, in ones
    a = empty(shape, dtype, order)

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```